Minimal pair /u/ and /ʊ/
I notice the pronunciation of "Kommunismus" contains two distinct phonemes: /u/ and /ʊ/, which seem to form a minimal pair. It seems to me the letter "u" without the umlaut represents two possible phonemes. Certain words are marked with /u/ in their dictionary pronunciation: du, Fuß, Mut, Hubschrauber, zu, zuerst, zuletzt, and other zu-words, while others call for /ʊ/: und, Ungeheuer, drucken, dunkel, Kunde, muss, Luft, Lust, etc. I just realized that I've never learned the relevant rules governing when to pronounce a word containing "u" with /u/ or /ʊ/, and that this seems as complicated as the English minimal pair /u/ and /ʊ/ which often confuse learners and get reduced to one by people learning English. So it seems that in order to better learn German pronunciation and accurately say things in German it's important for us to keep /u/ and /ʊ/ straight.
On the other hand, Wikipedia mentions many speakers in a lot of German speaking areas don't distinguish between the two and realize /ʊ/ as /u/: this page and this page. Given that they seem to be two distinct phonemes in standard German, my questions are:

To what extent are they distinguished? Do they collapse into one sound/phone for some speakers as Wikipedia seems to suggest?
How do I know when to pronounce a "u" word with /u/ and when with /ʊ/? What are the relevant rules?
Any pointers to additional resources discussing this minimal pair and the governing rules would be highly appreciated as well!


What's your definition of "minimal pair"?

As a German native, I can tell you I hear no difference in the sound of the u in Kommunismus, only in their length (/u/ is long and /ʊ/ is short). This is also the case for all the examples you gave.

Minimal pairs (conjugated or declined forms link to the base entry):

Buhle, Bulle
Rubel, rubbel
Spuk, spuck
duzend, Dutzend
Buße, Busse

The distinction between tense or long and lax or short vowels is fundamental. It is not always marked orthographically, but as the above examples show, there's always a short vowel in front of double consonants ll, bb, ss, with ck and tz counting as double. Conversely, h and ß are used to indicate that the preceding vowel is long.
There are dialects that have lax or short vowels where the standard has tense or long vowels. Some of these shortenings have become acceptable in Standard German. For instance, the entry for duschen allows both pronunciations. "Small words" such as du, zu will often have a short vowel when they are unstressed.

First things first: In the standard, /u/, in constrast to /u:/, does only appear in unstressed syllables, like in Kommunismus.
There are no minimal pairs for tense/lax pairs such as /ʊ/ and /u/ in unstressed syllables, because they are in complementary distribution. They are not really different phonemes. Furthermore, it must be noted that unstressed vowels besides /ə/ and /​ɐ/ are not really that common and appear mostly in loanwords or in composites, where it is doubtful if the vowels are really completely stress-free.
Lax forms are used in closed syllables (i.e. ending in a consonant) and tense forms are used in open syllables (i.e. ending in a vowel). In Kom-mu-nis-mus, the first "u" is in an open syllable, thus /u/, and the second "u" is in a closed syllable, thus /ʊ/.
If you have ever looked at a German vowel chart, you will see that the lax forms of the closed vowels /ɪ/, /ʏ/, /ʊ/  are very close to the tense forms of the middle vowels /e/, /ø/, /o/. That leads to a problem in unstressed syllables: An "ü" might sound like a "ö" and so on. While I cannot attest this for "-ismus", I have heard many speakers, including myself, saying /hyp'no:zə/ instead of /hʏp'no:zə/ in careful speech, because that makes it harder to mistake the first vowel as "ö".
Some dialects, especially in the south, have a weaker or non-existent difference in the vowel qualities of /u/ and /ʊ/ and can be described as to have only one vowel quality /u/, with the difference between tense and lax being mainly one of length. Because unstressed vowels are always short, there is no difference between their realisations of /u/ and /ʊ/. That is what the Wikipedia list was about.
As a learner, it will only ever useful for you to distinguish /ʊ/ and /u:/, not /ʊ/ and /u/, and you can do this by length.

I'm confused by the statement that /ʊ/ and /u/ have no minimal pairs: what about unstressed syllables that have a double consonant letter after them? I found a source, cited in my answer, that mentions words such as guttieren [ɡʊˈtiːʁən] vs goutieren [ɡuˈtiːʁən] and konsumieren [kɔnzuˈmiːʁən] vs. summieren [zʊˈmiːʁən]: do you disagree with these transcriptions? In your accent, are double consonant letters actually pronounced as long consonant sounds?

@sumelic You got me. I should have written of "orthographically open syllables". I did not know the word "guttieren", but I doubt that I can tell "guttieren" and "goutieren" apart. I do agree with the transcriptions. And no, my accent does not have geminated consonants.

Thanks for clarifying! I didn't know it either, I just found it by searching for words ending in "-uttieren"

I'm glad to hear that even native speakers have a hard time distinguishing, e.g., Müller from Möller. I have trouble with it too. My friend, a native English speaker like me, says he can pronounce them differently but it "uses every muscle in his face" :-p

@qdread That only applies to unstressed vowels. No native speaker should have trouble distinguishing "Müller" from "Möller" or "Busse" from "Buße".

@sumelic: I doubt that a distinction between «guttieren» and «goutieren» could be found in actual speech, even if you examined recordings of the best trained professional speakers.

@mach: Do you have contrasts between any of the other unstressed vowel pairs listed by Becker (page 87), such as Komitee [kom-] vs. Kommode [kɔm-], Imitation [im-] vs. Immigration [ɪm-]

@sumelic: I believe Becker is correct to conclude that there is no opposition between tense and lax vowels in unstressed syllables: «Somit belegen die oben diskutierten Daten nicht, dass die Vokalopposition in unbetonten Silben aufrechterhalten wird» (p. 91).

To interpret phonetic transcriptions without getting confused, you need to keep in mind both length and vowel quality. Length is marked in the IPA by putting the triangular colon "ː" after the vowel.  But as a practical matter, there's only a two-way distinction in terms of phonemes.
In stressed syllables, there can be a "short u" sound, typically transcribed as /ʊ/, and a "long u" sound, typically transcribed as /uː/. David Vogt's answer gives examples of these. What Wikipedia is saying is that some accents of German have a clear distinction in both length and quality, whereas other accents rely more on length alone to differentiate these phonemes. But in either case, a two-way distinction exists: the phonemic distinction is not collapsed for speakers who pronounce Stunde as [ˈʃtundə], because they would pronounce the "long u" vowel phoneme as a long vowel [uː], as in Fuß [ˈfuːs] and Mut [ˈmuːt].
In unstressed syllables, all vowels are phonetically shortened. This is how we get [u] in [kɔmuˈnɪsmʊs]. Since the shortening is predictable from the position of the stress, you can consider it a variant (allophone) of the "long u" phoneme /uː/ (compare Kommune [kɔˈmuːnə], where the vowel is stressed and long).
Per this paper:

In German, vowel reduction in such cases can be observed as a shortening of
long vowels (Foto [ˈfoːto] – Fotograf [fotoˈɡraːf] – Fotografie [fotoɡra
ˈfiː]). A change of vowel quality from tense to lax is less frequent, and vowels are never reduced to schwa.

("Unstressed Vowels in German Learner English: An Instrumental Study", by Lukas Soenning, page 165)
The only difference between unstressed [ʊ] and unstressed [u] is vowel quality, and I don't think that difference is necessarily very noticeable all the time. But in theory, they do contrast in Standard German: you'd expect to find [ʊ] in cases where the vowel is followed by a consonant cluster or a double consonant letter, whereas [u] is expected to occur before a single-written consonant. This is the same as the rule for when you find [ʊ] vs. [uː] in a stressed syllable.
"Das Vokalsystem der deutschen Standardsprache", by Thomas Becker, page 87, gives guttieren  [ɡʊˈtiːʁən] vs goutieren [ɡuˈtiːʁən] as an example of a minimal pair and konsumieren [kɔnzuˈmiːʁən]  vs. summieren [zʊˈmiːʁən] as an example of a near-minimal pair.
